# Couldn't find NBU Payments API in Google Developers console

Tags: google-console-developer, google-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Pay in my website using OminChannel method. the official documentation mentions

To open the Google API Library, from the Navigation menu, select APIs & Services > Library.
Search for "NBU Payments API". Select the correct result and click Enable.

But I can't find this in my Google API Library conosle.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me know did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register yourself as a merchant first

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same problem and we contacted Google Pay India Bussiness Support. They said that the Omni Channel method is an **invite**-only feature and asked us to use Android intent or UPI Collect call.